# Transpose and dot product (Check the logic)

Tags: inner-products, transpose

Suppose $Q^T$ equals $Q^{-1}$ (transpose equals inverse, so $Q^TQ^{-1} = 1$).

a)Show that the columns $q_l, ... , q_n$ are unit vectors: $||q_1||^2 = 1$.

b)Show that every two columns of $Q$ are perpendicular: $q_1^{T}q_2 = 0$.

This problem is connected with the definition of dot product: multiplication of pairwised columns and rows.

So, a)by the definition of dot product if $i = j$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n q_i^2 = 1$

b) The dot product isn't defined for i does't equal to j. So, when i does't equal to j, then $q_1^{T}q_2 = 0$.

Please correct my logic, because i am not sure if i am on the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Q^TQ=I$, we have $(Q^TQ)_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
  1 &\ i=j\\
  0           &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$ 
Also, from matrix multiplication, note that $(Q^TQ)_{ij}=(q_i \cdot q_j)$. Hence, 
\begin{equation}
(q_i \cdot q_j)=\begin{cases}
  1 &\ i=j\\
  0           &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This completes both proofs.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
Bu i have small question about the definition of dot product: It is defined only for i = j. If iy doesn't hold, can we say, that the q_i * q_j = 0(even if it is undefined by definition of dot product)?
I hope you understood me:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "it is only defined for $i=j$"; certainly you can take the dot product of two different vectors.

Comment: I think i get it! We have such answer, because if i = j, then by definition of identity matrix we get 1, If not - 0.
Am i right?